# Restore original MacOS on my 2009 iMac

Tags: macos, imac, restore

I have two machines 1 iMac 2009 24” and one MacBook Pro 2017 touchbar. The iMac I cannot open at all as I erased everything from the Macintosh HD. I am trying to fix by using Catalina on the MacBook Pro to create a bootable USB to boot the iMac from.

The 2009 iMac had two partitions in its Harddrive, one for HD Mactintosh and one for BootCamp. I wanted to wipe everything so I shutdown the machine then started it while hitting `CMD + R` then I get the restore window and I choose restore Mac OS then it asks me to sign it to my apple store and I enter my App Store details but it gives this error `This item is temporarily unavailable` I wonder how I can get the macOS restored if anyone could please help as I am kinda stuck and don't know how to solve this.

I have downloaded the El Capitan .dmg file and erased a 32GB USB stick to macOS journaled but I don’t know how I can make it bootable from the dmg file? And then how I can use the bootable USB to install the macOS?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you actually mean the original OS X? I ask because early 2009 iMacs originally had OS X 10.5.6 installed and late 2009 iMacs originally had OS X 10.6.2 installed. Or, do you want El Capitan OS X 10.11 as shown in your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos) Note: I tried the link to download El Capitan and am currently able to download the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I want to download any version which then I can update it to the latest. I already downloaded the El Capitan OS X but I don’t know how to make it bootable and how to boot from it on my iMac?

Comment: You should update your question to indicate what you are currently asking.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I’ve updated my question as requested. I hope you could help me.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean for this to be closed. I know you edited the question, but you should have removed the part where you indicate you are having problems downloading. This made you question appear to be a duplicate. While it is still a duplicate, it is not a duplicate of the question in the link.

Comment: @DavidAnderson so what shall I do? :/

Comment: I posted an answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/388456#388456).

Comment: @DavidAnderson Could you check my question here please? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390063/restore-from-timemachine-after-merging-all-partitions