# Restore from TimeMachine after merging all partitions

Tags: time-machine, disk-utility, partition, restore

I have a MacBook Pro Mac1 with multiple partitions as shown below. I want to restore this Mac1 from a timeMachine of another Mac2 which has only one partition and I want to do the restore so that Mac1 will end up in one partition as well. I closed Mac1 then hit `Command+R` when it booted then when I chose restore from TimeMachine it asks me which partition I want to restore to but I want to restore it into one full partition. So, I've tried merging the partitions of Mac1 using disk utility before doing the restore but I doesn't allow me since everything is grayed out as shown below. Both Macs are macOS Catalina. Any advice?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your goal to completely wipe Mac1 and restore it with the TM of Mac2? If so, just erase the Mac1 drive. Don't go into partition, hit the Erase button, which erases *all* partitions on the disk.

Comment: As @At0mic said, best option is to erase the APFS Container or APPLE SSD. After you do that, you just need to use the Time Machine option in macOS Recovery. A simpler solution would be to wipe Mac1 and then set up a brand new installation of macOS Catalina. Then, use Migration Assistant to transfer data over from Mac2.

Comment: @Todd How the second solution is simpler?

Comment: It is simpler because sometimes, restoring from a Time Machine backup can convert Drive Formats from APFS to HFS and things like that. I just meant that using Migration Assistant avoids things like that.

Comment: @Todd Both Macs are running **macOS Catalina** so, "because sometimes, restoring from a Time Machine backup can convert Drive Formats from APFS to HFS" is not applicable here as **macOS Catalina** requires **APFS** and is not going to convert **APFS** to **HFS** for a **macOS Catalina** install.

Comment: I have had experiences with macOS Catalina where restoring a Catalina backup converts APFS to HFS even though macOS Mojave and above require APFS.